# "herself included"

Tags: pronouns

In the NYTimes article today there is a sentence:

> "Ai Xiaoming, 63, a prominent documentary filmmaker, said many women, *herself* included, had never been advised ..."

The rationale is that Xiaoming includes herself among the women. But couldn't we also think of it as ... *she* had never been advised? Also, let's take out the many women. We have now:

> Ai Xiaoming, 63 a prominent documentary filmmaker, said *she* had never been advised ...

Which is correct?

Comment: That is exactly what it does mean. She numbered herself among the many women who had never been advised.

Comment: Well, in the sentence from the NYT, the subject of the content clause is *many women* and the phrase *herself included* is a parenthetical phrase adding extra information - a bit as if it had been put in brackets. In your version, of course, *she* is the subject of the clause, as if the *main* information she wanted to give was that she hadn't been advised. It also doesn't say that many other women hadn't been advised. This isn't the case in the original sentence. So your sentence is not better or worse, it just means something different from the original sentence.

Comment: I think both of the above answers should help you out. Also, there is a degree of emphasis with "herself included", especially if we know something about her.   ~not only many women, but -even- her, a well traveled expert documentarian~ had never been advised.

Comment: Short Answer: Both are correct. Long Answer: But stylistically, I would go with what the NYT had written for the emphasis it provides. I suspect it is to highlight the plight of all women, not only of the director.

Comment: To add to @Araucaria's comment, there's also *she herself had never been advised*, which suggests that others might have been; it would be rather contrary to the sense of "many women, herself included" here.

Answer (score 1):

As Araucaria says in a comment above, the two partial sentences mean two different things.

First,

> Ai Xiaoming, 63, a prominent documentary filmmaker, said many women, herself included, had never been advised

explicitly asserts something about the experience of many women and identifies Ai Xiaoming as one of them. Because the initial assertion is attributed to Ai Xiaoming (in paraphrase), the reflexive pronoun *herself* is appropriate as a way to include her among the "many women" already identified.

Second,

> Ai Xiaoming, 63, a prominent documentary filmmaker, said she had never been advised ...

limits the scope of the assertion to Ai Xiaoming's own personal experience of not being advised [about something]. It does not address the question of whether her experience was unique or was something that had happened to many other women.

Syntactically, both *herself* in the first example and *she* in the second do their intended jobs quite satisfactorily; but in terms of meaning, they serve different mistresses.